# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o203.save

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm running everything locally and using visual studio code. In the code I am querying some views and then saving the result in a file in parquet format. The problem is that it doesn't let me execute this line of code, can someone guide me on the solution?

```
gold_FC.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").save(pathGuardado, format="parquet")
```

I get this error:

> "name": "Py4JJavaError",
> "message": "An error occurred while calling o203.save.\n: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 5 in stage 11.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.0 in stage 11.0 (TID 14) (192.168.0.15 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)\r\n\tat org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)

The strange thing is that the rest of the code in Spark lets me run successfully.I tried passing the result from spark to pandas and it won't let me either.

`df_gold = gold_FC.toPandas()`

I get a different error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o189.collectToPython.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (192.168.0.15 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker exited unexpectedly (crashed)
> at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator$$anonfun$1.applyOrElse(PythonRunner.scala:612)

Comment: Just blue skying here, but are you confident that the module knows how to save in parquet format?  And are you sure the path is a valid path at the time you run this command?  Can you do `open(pathGuardado,'w').write("testing\n")`?

Comment: Yes i can. Im sure this module can save it in parquet format, i tested this code in databricks and it works but i need to run this locally.

Comment: I think the problem is some cluster or Windows configuration issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The error points to an issue while executing code on the executors. Check the executors logs if applicable. Also, sharing the full script might help others figure out where the issue could be.